# Log back configuration error while running JUnit

Tags: junit, logstash, logstash-configuration, rollingfileappender, logstash-file

I configured logback.xml in my application and it's working fine. But after working some days, while running Junit test cases i got the below error.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[STDOUT] - Appender [STDOUT] failed to append. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert 1 of typejava.lang.Integer
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[STDOUT] - Appender [STDOUT] failed to append. java.lang.NullPointerException
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[STDOUT] - Appender [STDOUT] failed to append. java.lang.NullPointerException
            at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:169)
            at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithConventions(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:82)
            at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:60)
            at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:117)
            at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:292)
            at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:265)
            at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:228)
            at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:201)
            at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
            at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
            at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
            at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
            at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:75)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:347)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:306)
            at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:127)
            at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
            at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
            at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
            at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
            at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
            at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
            at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
            at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
            at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
            at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
            at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
            at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
            at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
            at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
            at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
            at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
            at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
            at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
            at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
            at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
            at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
11:56:03.388 [main] ERROR o.s.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@2b30a42c] to prepare test instance [com.test.demo.cq.model.CqTest@f107c50]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
            at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
            at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
            at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
            at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
            at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
            at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
            at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
            at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
            at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
            at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
            at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
            at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
            at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
            at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
            at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
            at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
            at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
            at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
            at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
            at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Below is my logback.xml code

```
<configuration>
    <property name="HOME_LOG" value="logs/app.log" />
    <appender name="classicConsoleAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender name="jsonConsoleAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder" />
    </appender>
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="classicConsoleAppender" />
        <!-- <appender-ref ref="jsonConsoleAppender"/> -->
    </root>

    <appender name="STDOUT"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${HOME_LOG}</file>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <maxIndex>1</maxIndex>
            <fileNamePattern>logs/archived/app.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
            </fileNamePattern>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <triggeringPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <MaxFileSize>1MB</MaxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>

        <encoder
            class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
            <providers>
                <timestamp>
                    <timeZone>UTC</timeZone>
                </timestamp>
                <uuid>
                    <fieldName>id</fieldName>
                    <strategy>time</strategy>
                    <ethernet>00:C0:F0:3D:5B:7C</ethernet>
                </uuid>
                <callerData>
                    <classFieldName>classname</classFieldName>
                    <methodFieldName>method</methodFieldName>
                    <fileFieldName>file</fileFieldName>
                    <lineFieldName>line</lineFieldName>
                </callerData>
                <threadName>
                    <fieldName>thread</fieldName>
                </threadName>
                <loggerName />
                <logLevel />
                <message />
                <mdc />
                <arguments>
                    <includeNonStructuredArguments>true</includeNonStructuredArguments>
                </arguments>
                <logstashMarkers />
                <stackTrace />
            </providers>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

I am unable to figure it out the issue. It seems Rolling file is not generating after reached max size. Any help Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Update your rolling policy with

```
<minIndex>1</minIndex>
<maxIndex>10</maxIndex>
```

Comment: same error which i posted. instead of 1 its showing 10 ```java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[STDOUT] - Appender [STDOUT] failed to append. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert 10 of typejava.lang.Integer ```

Comment: It looks known bug for Logback.. Try to update your logback version https://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-1293?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Achangehistory-tabpanel